# Configuring KVM inside Ubuntu Hyper-V client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hyper-v, linux-kvm, hypervisor

Is it possible to run KVM on an Ubuntu 18.04 guest in Hyper-V on Windows 10? Or any other hypervisor inside the guest?

After installing KVM I run:

> sudo kvm-ok

and it tells me my CPU does not support KVM extensions.

And to foreshadow:  "Why are you trying to run a hypervisor inside a hypervisor.... I want to play with https://hypercontainer.io and don't have a bare metal Linux machine to play with.

Comment: With nested virtualization, your options are very limited. Try VMware Player or Workstation (trial versions are available).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article
[Running KVM Nested in Microsoft Hyper-V](https://ianmarmour.com/2016/04/23/running-kvmxen-nested-in-microsoft-hyper-v/)
reports this procedure :

1. Download this
   [PowerShell script](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/blob/master/hyperv-tools/Nested/Enable-NestedVm.ps1)
   from Github (written by Microsoft)
2. Copy the script to your desktop
3. Open up an elevated PowerShell instance
4. Change current folder to the location of the PowerShell Script
5. Run the following command to allow for script execution in Powershell

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
   ```
6. Run `.\nameofscript.ps1 name-of-linux-vm-in-hyper-v`
7. If all goes well it should prompt you asking if you want to expose Virtualization Extensions. Answer Yes, also enable any other additions as you wish.
8. After the script completes, boot the VM in Hyper-V and you should now have access to the virtualization extensions required for KVM/XEN.

Comment: I agreed to shut down the HVMachine, enlarge RAM to 4GB, and all seemed fine, but after restarting the VM, it still says. `INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used`

Comment: To understand what the script does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry about answering this ~6 years old question.

Seems to me that the way of switching on Hyper-V's nested virtualization on a VM has been greatly improved.

According to Microsoft's documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/enable-nested-virtualization :

- Make sure the host CPU is either **Intel processor with VT-x and EPT technology** or **AMD EPYC / Ryzen processor or later**, and
- Run the following command in a *PowerShell* terminal to switch on Hyper-V's nested virtualization on a specific VM:

  ```
  Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
  ```

  where `<VMName>` is the name of the VM.

I've just set up a guest VM installed Debian 12 x64 and then KVM on a Windows 10's Hyper-V and switched on the VM's nested virtualization. Now I'm using *Cockpit* to set up a Debian 11 x64 KVM guest while writing this answer.